# Transforming inequalities over the real numbers

Tags: inequality

Given integers a and b and the relation a <= b, intuitively I feel I can transform this inequality into a strict inequality like this:

a < b + 1

Conversely, I should be able to transform the strict inequality a < b to a non-strict one like this:

a + 1 <= b

My question is, is there any way I can do the same transformations if a and b are real numbers, WITHOUT introducing some kind of slack/surplus variables? I.e. is there a way to do the transformation by only using constants? I do not feel that it should be possible due to the nature of the real numbers, but I would just like to find out.

Comment: Excluding "dummy variables", I don't see how one could do it. But with those, I suppose you know that you can do $\forall \epsilon>0: a<b+\epsilon$ for $a\leq b$.

Comment: Yea, that was the only solution I could see. It complicates an algorithm I am working on though, so I just wanted to know if there was some other solution.

Comment: Maybe you can show us what the algorithm is and what you really want to achieve? There might be another way that doesn't involve what you're asking here.

Answer (score 2):

With continous transforms, you can't.

Assume you had a continous $f$ and $b$, $c$ such that $$
  x < b \text{ exactly if } f(x) \leq c \text{.}
$$ Pick a sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n \to b$ from below, i.e. $x_n < b$ for all $n$. You'd then have $$
  f(x_n) \leq c \text{ for all $n$}
$$
and because $f$ is continuous also $$
  f(b) \leq c \text{,}
$$
but that (according to the initial assumption) means $$
  b < b
$$
which of course is impossible.